# Reshape dataframe with first column values as column names and second column values as row values in r

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like that, just with more values and variables:

| Column_Name_1 | Column_Name_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value 3 |
| Value 2 | Value 4 |

And i want it to look like that:

| Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Value 3 | Value 4 |

Do you maybe have an easy solution for that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try `unstack` + `data.frame`

```
> data.frame(t(unstack(rev(df))), row.names = NULL, check.names = FALSE)
  Value 1 Value 2
1 Value 3 Value 4
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Column_Name_1 = c("Value 1", "Value 2"), Column_Name_2 = c("Value 3", 
"Value 4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option -

```
setNames(data.frame(t(df[-1]), row.names = NULL), df$Column_Name_1)

#  Value 1 Value 2
#1 Value 3 Value 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't use the values as colnames

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
df %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames("Column_Name_1") %>% 
  t() %>% as_tibble()

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `Value 1` `Value 2`
  <chr>     <chr>    
1 Value 3   Value 4
```